# DDD - How to correctly implement authorization service with Identity in .NET Core MVC app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, domain-driven-design

I have a `MemoController` which gets some memo (with name, description, id, userId). Each memo belongs to one user. I created an API controller to get memo by id.

```
[HttpGet("{memoId}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(Guid memoId)
{
    // A way to get user id
    //var userId = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? Guid.Parse(User.Identity.Name) : Guid.Empty;

    var memo = await _memoService.GetByIdAsync(memoId); // Can get memo from other users

    if (memo == null) return NotFound();

    return Json(memo);
}
```

Every user should only have access to their own memos. The problem is that right now a user can obtain memos belonging to other users. Is it possible to inject something like `UserMemoService` which gets the user id from `System.Security.Claims`? I want to do it following the DDD principles (not implementing service in Controller's constructor or more complex mess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need resource based authorization. There are different implementations, depending on your preferences. For example, you could implement your own authorization policy which would use your custom service that checks if user requesting document is the same one as document owner.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x